# Is it possible to write a plugin to open a directory and generate some files in it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I would love to write a plugin like yo plugin but with some UI. But yo could not work before you open a directory in vscode. What I need is to select a directory in my UI and automatically generate codes.

Can any one tell me which API to use to do such things and I will dig into it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `showOpenDialog()` method from the [`vscode.window` namespace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_window) to let the user pick a directory if none is currently opened. With `canSelectFiles: false` and `canSelectFolders: true`, it turns into a folder picker. After that, you can run the `"vscode.openFolder"` command to open the newly created workspace.

```ts
vscode.window.showOpenDialog({
    canSelectFolders: true,
    canSelectFiles: false
}).then(folders => {
    if (folders != null && folders.length > 0) {
        setupProject(folders[0].fsPath);
        vscode.commands.executeCommand("vscode.openFolder", folders[0]);
    }
});
```

This is basically the approach we take for the ["init project" command in the Haxe extension](https://github.com/vshaxe/vshaxe/blob/5b6c72ca9b0e4ceaa73a9ef7dfefdc0e1a9f3eab/src/vshaxe/commands/InitProject.hx#L17-L25).

Comment: I'm also using showOpenDialog and currently got that equal to a variable. I printed the object to the console and noticed that the properties (_creator, _nextState, and _state) were either "Object" or "null". Is it acceptable not to define those? Like you haven't above.

Comment: Those sound like some internal properties (due to the underscore prefix, and they're also not part of the API). See the `OpenDialogOptions` interface (all of the properties are optional, indicated by the `?`): https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#OpenDialogOptions